# Overriding java class in bundle from another bundle

Tags: java, maven, osgi, bundle, apache-felix

Can an inherited bundle override the java classes in parent bundle. I would like to change the one of the class in the bundle so for this i will use inheritance concept to have a new bundle inheriting parent bundle. Please let me know how can i do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean under the word "inherit"? You can embed bundles or create fragment bundles (that belong to a host-bundle).

Comment: @Balazs Zsoldos suppose i have a bundle Hello which have a.java class in it with some methods but now i want a bundle which have all the methods in a.java class but only one method with different functionality as in bundle Hello. So i am just asking is there any way to do so ??

Comment: Why come to StackOverflow to ask whether something is possible?? Why not just try it first, and then come here if it didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use normal Java inheritance.

The bundle containing the base class will need to export the package to which that class belongs, and the bundle containing the subclass will need to import the same package.